# How to add fresh data to an existing data in React-query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a code which calls an API with a certain number of data and receives them. I wish for the 2nd call to add the newly retrieved data to be added to the already existing data using React-query library.

My code so far is :

```
const fetchData = async ({queryKey : [key , pages]}) => {
  
  return (await fetch(`http://jservice.io/api/random?count=${pages}`)).json()
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(10);
  const {isLoading, error, data , } = useInfiniteQuery(['general' , state], fetchData , {keepPreviousData : true} )

  
  setTimeout(() => {
    setState(20)
  }, 4444);

  console.log(data)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      h
    </div>
  );
}
```

I wish to hit the 4444 time line marker by adding the newly fetched data to the existing data solely by using React-query hooks.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to gave 20 or 30 items after the timeout?

Comment: @Domino987 I wish to add to the existing data as normally I would do with a push array. Do I have to do it manually or this extensive library has something for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `fetchNextPage` from the query. Call this to load the next page. Either onClick or after a timeout.

```
<button onClick={fetchNextPage}>Load more</button>
```

Also do not set `setTimeout` in the render function, since it will be called and executed on every render, which will remove your progress.
Dont track the current page yourself but let react-query handle it.
Just set the `getNextPageParam` function to return how you need to get the next page and extract that as `pageParam` from the query context in `fetchData`

To render the data, you need to map over the pages returned from the query inside data and for each page, query over the items returned:

```
{isSuccess &&
  data.pages.map((page, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
        {page.results.map((poke) => (
            <div key={poke.name}>{poke.name}</div>
         ))}
    </div>
))}
```

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-bartik-pl4pd?file=/src/App.js) with pokemon.

Comment: The API does not have a next page so that fails. This is not what I am trying to achieve here. I want to add to the existing data regardless of the page.

Comment: It does not matter if it is a page or some new random data that needs to be appended. As you can see in my updated sandbox.

Comment: so  there is no way I can use {keepPreviousData : true} and add to the existing data?

Comment: Yes you can set the on success callback, access both data in that and set the data via the query client with setQueryData.

Comment: is it possible to access all pages in only one array do access data without render. To use on react-select options?

Comment: Just saw the comment. Do you mean you want to map over them all at once? you could just do: data.pages.flat()